# How to use RegExp in Directive with validation with Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have 8 angular application. and I have a directive with a RegExp for youtube and vimeo validation.

But after I declared the RegExp I can't use it in the directive.

So I have this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `urlPattern` static as well, otherwise it's only visible to non-static methods. You will also then need to refer to it as `EcheqUrlValidator.urlPattern`.

Comment: As an alternative, I often simply define a non-exported `const` outside of the body of the class. That way I can easily refer to the value just by name without also prefixing the class name. I guess that goes against some people's ideals about encapsulation, but it doesn't upset me too much :)